Easy interest rate question, but coursera marked it wrong
Here is an easy interest rate question from one of the finance courses on coursera:

If the present value of \$400 paid one year from now is \$320, what is the one-year interest rate?  (Note:  this number is also known as the discount rate.)

I took the difference over 400 to get 80/400 = 0.20, but it was counted wrong. I'm wondering if I did something wrong or if the site's answer is wrong. The only other thing I could think of trying is 80/320 = 0.25. Any advice appreciated, thank you.

It (400-320)/320 right? The final value minus the initial, then the whole thing divided by the initial.

You need to think of what you are trying to solve here. More generally, you look at the question what r is in the equation PV*(1+r)^n = FV, with n being the years (assuming it's always full years). Or in your wording you have the FB as 400 and PV as 320 and want the (discount) rate. Here, (FV/PV)^(1/n) -1 = r , or (400/320)^(1/1)-1 = r which is identical to =80/320.

What you want is to solve $$ 400=320\left(1+\frac{r}{m}\right)^{nm}$$ for $r$. Here $n$ is the interest period (which in your case is 1) and $m$ is the compounding frequency (which you have not defined). For example with annual compounding ($m=1$) or with simple compounding ($m=\frac{1}{n}$), $r$ works out as $0.25$; with continuous compounding ($m=\infty$), $r=0.22314$ ...etc.
